# WordPress Child Theme Styles Not Being Applied

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, media-queries

I am working with the Ocean-WP child theme.  I have created a stylesheet in the child theme as I know well not to add styles to the parent stylesheet.  The problem is none of the styles I write in the child stylesheet are being applied. 
Why?

```
/*
Theme Name: OceanWP Child
Theme URI: https://oceanwp.org/
Description: OceanWP WordPress theme example child theme.
Author: 
Author URI: https://oceanwp.org/
Template: oceanwp
Version: 1.0
*/

@import url("../oceanwp/style.css");
form{
    background-color:blue !important;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 374px){
#page-title{
    font-size:3.5rem;
}

}
```

Comment: Why not try their own child theme available at https://github.com/oceanwp/oceanwp-child-theme. Remove your current child theme, upload and activate their child theme and put your style inside the `style.css` file of the new child theme. Please note that you don't need to use `@import url("../oceanwp/style.css");` in the child theme.

Answer (score 0):

Find the css name from "View Source" on browser. Search style.css and find out the name. Now add the code below to your functions.php file. 
The reason wordpress doesn't show updated child theme css because of query string. All you need to do is change the query string version with the code below and clear your browser cache. Enjoy.

```
function update-child-css() {
wp_enqueue_style('child-theme-css-name', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/style.css', array(), '1.0.1' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'update-child-css');
```